# How to secure WCF with Third party certificates?

Tags: wcf, certificate

I am hosting a secured WCF service (transport level security) which needs to authenticate users with third party client certificates. To accept those client certificates, I have binded my IIS7 with third party Server Certificate. Theoretically speaking this should work perfectly. But it is not, It continues to give error as 
*The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.*

Does anyone having idea on how to make it possible in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [WCF Security Guidance](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex - they have tons of How-To's and extensive coverage and step-by-step explanations for all things WCF security related.

The one How-To most interesting to you would probably be:

[How To – Use Certificate Authentication and Message Security in WCF](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Use%20Certificate%20Authentication%20and%20Message%20Security%20in%20WCF%20calling%20from%20Windows%20Forms&referringTitle=How%20Tos)